# Stop "Unnamed (Index = 0)" is unallocated

Tags: android, esri, esri-maps, arcgis-android-api

I am using esri offline maps and getting routes with route task . But facing this issue that `Stop "Unnamed (Index = 0)" is unallocated. esri`.
Any help would be appreciated. If required i'll edit and put the code.

error

`Stop "Unnamed (Index = 0)" is unlocated.
Stop "Unnamed (Index = 1)" is unlocated.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but that means you instantiated a Stop with an invalid coordinate. Could be because you got Latitude/Longitude mixed up, Esri uses X/Y sometimes, X referring to Longitude and Y referring to Latitude. Could also be because you have an incorrect SpatialReference. Or it could be it's just a bad coordinate.